# CSS assignment to create a restaurant menu categories

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

i need to create a menu categories as like this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jX8mt.jpg)

but the result turns out like this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wd7a1.jpg)

The description div keep stacking on the photo div; it's funny that when i copy the code from the training material it works fine, am i missing something here?

The code:

```
 <div id="main-content" class="container">
 <section class="row">
  <div class="menu-item-tile col-md-6">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-5">
        <div class="menu-item-photo">
          <div>D01</div>
          <img class="img-responsive" width="250" height="150" src="images/menu/B/B-1.jpg" alt="Item">
        </div>
        <div class="menu-item-price">$10.95<span> (pint)</span> $14.95 <span>(quart)</span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="menu-item-description col-sm-7">
        <h3 class="menu-item-title">Veal with Mixed Vegetables</h3>
        <p class="menu-item-details">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque inventore esse minima incidunt impedit. Asperiores, voluptatem. Sint aspernatur provident, rem odio dolorem eaque voluptatibus modi reprehenderit minima, itaque cupiditate totam.Asperiores, voluptatem. Sint aspernatur provident, rem odio dolorem eaque voluptatibus modi reprehenderit minima, itaque cupiditate totam.Asperiores, voluptatem. Sint aspernatur provident, rem odio dolorem eaque voluptatibus modi reprehenderit minima, itaque cupiditate totam.</p>
        <!--no matter the screen size changing, the ratio of photo remain col-sm-5 and description remain on col-sm-7-->
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr class="visible-xs">
  </div>
```

Comment: ....Where is CSS  ?

Comment: Try to remove the `width` and `height` attributes from the `img`

Comment: i tried copying only the html code form the training material to my new file and it still work, plus the instructor haven't apply the css on it yet and it already looking tidy

Comment: tried width and height remove, it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would not recommend bootstrap because there is little personality and everything looks the same.

Aside from that, I would suggest you take a look at these two links [1](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_product_card.asp) & [2](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_coupon.asp).

These won't have a ready-made option for you, but you can build off them.

Comment: Thank you so much!! it seems able to solve the problem; can i have more sources for building content without using bootstrap gird system?

Comment: Glad it worked! Make sure to give me a checkmark to help others who have this question.

Comment: @Rex.august check out [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp) It will help you a lot!